# Countdown timer to start of HTML5 video

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to get a 3 second timer to display and then start the HTML5 video. What I have so far is a hover to start the video and it works great. I need to have a timer display when you hover over the video and when that timer hits 0 it will start the video. Any suggestions. This is the code I have for the video hover to start.

```
   $('#player2').hover(function(){
      var that = $(this);
         if(!$('#'+that.data('video')).is(':visible')){
           $('video:visible')[0].play();
              $('video:visible').fadeIn('normal', function(){
    $('video')[0].play();
                 $('#'+that.data('video')).fadeOut('normal', function(){
               $('#'+that.data('video'))[0].play();
             });
          });
        }else{
          $('#'+that.data('video'))[0].play();
         }

       }, function(){
        $('video:visible')[0].play();
        });
```

Comment: Have you tried looking into `setTimeout()` function for javascript? It waits X amount of miliseconds to continue a script. `3000` being 3 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Granted this is not the most elegant way to do things.  But to give you an idea.

```
var running = false;
$('#counter').hide();
$('#player2').hover(function(){
if(!running){
    running = true;
    var that = $(this); // get your that variable here
    $('#counter').html('3'); //counter animation 3
    $('#counter').show();
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#counter').html('2'); //counter animation 2
    },1000);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#counter').html('1'); //counter animation 1
    },2000);
    setTimeout(function() {
         if(!$('#'+that.data('video')).is(':visible')){  // the rest of your video code
            ....
           });    
    },3000);
 }
});
```

Fiddle example

http://jsfiddle.net/HevV7/

Comment: @user2958098 Please give feedback on the answers to your question, and or mark it as accepted if it helped you.

Comment: @user2958098 to the left of the question there should be a check mark you can click that to accept the answer.  Thank you

Comment: Did you create a id called counter in your HTML? If you did how did you  do it?

Comment: @user2958098 Just `<div id="counter"></div>` So I'm not sure how you want to do it but you will want to use `css` to move your counter to the middle of your `video` Look at my fiddle for the `css` and the `html`